# Undefined Native Modules

Tags: android, react-native, module, native, appsee

I'm new to react-native, I'm trying to use react-native-appsee for my app analytics, according to [appsee website documentations](https://www.appsee.com/docs/android/reactnative) it should be easy. I did everything exactly like the documentations but when I tried to run the app it gave me the undefined native module error
which says undefined is not an object (evaluating 'AppseeBridge.start').

I don't think it's appsee problem because I tried to make my own module using appsee java files and it didn't work either.
anyone could help me with fix this?

here is my dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12"

"react-native": "0.51.0"

"react-native-appsee": "^2.3.64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, apparently all I had to do was to create an appsee.js file and export the module then I could use it in my code!